# ASP.Net does not include sys.webforms for Safari 6.0.4

Tags: javascript, asp.net

On my webform page, MicrosoftAjaxWebForms is not included when browsed from this version of safari version/6.0.4 safari/536.29.13 (on Lion). There isn't a ScriptResource.axd for it while I have other script resources for telerik.

The browser capabilities state the ecma script version is 0.0 but js does in fact run.

I've tried to create a browser definition file but it doesn't seem to read that or apply the settings.

What can I do next?

Thank you.

Comment: Try that hot fix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600088

Comment: Or this one if you're on .NET 2.0/3.5:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2600100

Comment: KB2600088 does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your computer. And I uninstalled .net 4.5

Comment: What about KB2600100?

Comment: I'm on 4.0. I have the browser definition file partially working.
<browser id="Safari604" parentID="safari3plus"><identification><userAgent match="Safari" /></identification><capabilities><capability name="ecmascriptversion" value="3.0" /><capability name="w3cdomversion" value="1.0" /><capability name="supportscallback" value="true" />
      <capability name="supportsxmlhttp" value="true" />
      <capability name="browser"  value="MyBrowser" />
    </capabilities>
I can see MyBrowser but ecmaversion is still 0 and js is false
This was a big help http://forums.asp.net/t/955969.aspx/1

Comment: My issues turned out to be a problem with my 51degrees dat file, it was out of date and not auto updating. 51degrees is a mobile device detection redirector so to speak. 

This gave me the idea it was 51
http://51degrees.mobi/Support/Forum/tabid/65/forumid/2/threadid/2165/scope/posts/Default.aspx

In researching I found this an excellent resource on
how browser definition files work
http://forums.asp.net/t/955969.aspx/1